# Задача на вычисление квадратного корня. Длинная арифметика

Tags: арифметика

[image: попытка решить]

вычисление целого квадратного корня из целого числа. На этот раз мы будем использовать встроенную «длинную арифметику» языка Python, так что число может быть любой длины. К сожалению, стандартная функция sqrt из модуля math, не поддерживает работу с целыми числами произвольной длины, и результат её работы вещественное число 2. Поэтому в том случае, когда нужно именно целое значение, приходится использовать специальные методы.

Один из самых известных алгоритмов вычисления квадратного корня, известный ещё в Древней Греции, метод Герона Александрийского, который сводится к многократному применению формулы 3 1 a x = + i xi 1. 2 xi 1 Здесь a число, из которого извлекается корень, а xi и x 1 i предыдущее и следующее приближения (см. главу 9 из учебника для 10 класса). Фактически здесь вычисляется среднее арифметическое между x i и a / x 1 i 1. Пусть одно из этих значений меньше, чем a, тогда второе обязательно больше, чем a. Поэтому их среднее арифметическое с каждым шагом приближается к значению корня. Метод Герона «сходится» (то есть, приводит к правильному решению) при любом начальном приближении x 0 (не равном нулю). Например, можно выбрать начальное приближение x 0 = a. Приведённая формула служит для вычисления вещественного значения корня. Для того, чтобы найти целочисленное значение корня (то есть максимальное целое число, квадрат кото 2 Заметим, что возведение целого числа в степень 0,5 тоже даёт вещественное число. 3 Фактически эта формула результат применения метода Ньютона для решения нелинейных уравнений к уравнению 2 x = a.

рого не больше, чем a ), можно заменить оба деления на целочисленные, на языке Python это запишется так: x = (x + a // x)// 2 или привести выражение в скобках к общему знаменателю для того, чтобы использовать всего одно целочисленное деление: x = (x*x + a) // (2*x) Функция для вычисления квадратного корня может выглядеть так: def isqrt(a): x = a while True: x1 = (x*x + a)//(2*x) if x1 >= x: return x x = x1 Здесь наиболее интересный момент условие выхода из цикла. Как вы знаете, цикл с заголовком while True это бесконечный цикл, из которого можно выйти только с помощью оператора break или (в функции) с помощью return. Мы начинаем поиск с начального приближения x 0 = a, которое (при больших a ) заведомо больше правильного ответа. Поэтому каждое следующее приближение будет меньше предыдущего. А как только очередное приближение оказывается больше или равно предыдущему, мы нашли квадратный корень.

Как это записать в код?

Answer (score 0):

Это модификация метода Ньютона решения нелинейного уравнения.

```
def sqroot(number, eps):
    a = float(number) # из какого числа извлекаем
    x0=0 #предыдущее значение
    x1=a #начальное приближение
    while abs(x0-x1)>eps:
        x0=x1
        x1 = 0.5 * (x1 + a / x1) # x_(n+1) = 0.5 * (x_n +a / x_n)
    return x1

print(sqroot(9,0.00000001))

print(sqroot(2,0.001))
```